# Каким образом меняется размер clipPath?

Tags: html, css, css3, svg, inkscape

Господа, столкнулся я значит с такой задачей:

- Есть слайдер, все фото которые в него попадают(`180px/180px`), должны быть обрезаны по контуру.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для фигурной обрезки было решено использовать `SVG` маску.
В программе `Inkeskape`, создал холст `180/180` и набросал контур. 
Далее нашел в "И-нете" статьи о свойстве `clip-path: url(...);`. 
Скопировал из `svg файла` "путь", перенес все это дело в `HTML` песочницу и обрезал фотографию.
Результат - маленький контур (примерно `100*100px`) обрезает большую фотографию.
[Песочница на codepen](https://codepen.io/Jackkill/pen/dmPQWm?editors=1100)

Подскажите, как увеличить этот контур относительно фотографии и можно ли это делать через `css`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- У вас фотография имеет размер `600х800px` Поэтому и полигон в
  `Inkscape` для `clipPath` нужно было выбрать точно такого же размера.
  И тогда маску не нужно было бы уменьшать, увеличивать.
- Второй путь - загружаете фотографию в `Inkscape` и прямо
  сверху фотографии рисуете патч, который будет использован в качестве
  `clipPath` Но это на будущее.
- А сейчас можно пойти третьим путём.

Для увеличения размера клипа используем команду `transform="scale(N)"` Подбираете вручную. После увеличение `clipPath` сдвинется вправо и вниз.

Для позиционирования используете команду - `transform="translate(X Y)"`

В итоге формула для увеличения, позиционирования выглядит так:

```
transform="scale(3.3) translate(-11.7 -10)"
```

Внизу полный код, сравните его со своим исходным кодом и подкорректируйте немного `CSS`, так он был немного изменен мною для более точного позиционирования.

```css
HTML, BODY {
    height: 100%;
}

BODY {
    background: 
        linear-gradient( #EEE 1px, transparent 2px),
        linear-gradient( to right, #EEE 1px, transparent 2px);
    background-size: 1em 1em;
}

.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    background-color: gray;
    }

.catMask {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: calc(50% - 50px);
    width:250px;
    height: auto;
    
-webkit-clip-path: url(#svgPath);
    clip-path: url(#svgPath);
}
.maskItem {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">


 <!-- image start -->
<img src="https://www.goldennumber.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/florence-colgate-england-most-beautiful-face.jpg" alt="face" class="catMask">
<!-- image end -->
   
<!-- mask start -->
<!-- Created with Inkscape -->
<svg height="0" width="0" class="maskItem"   viewBox="0 0 600 800">
  <defs>
     <clipPath id="svgPath" transform="scale(3.3) translate(-11.7 -10)">
        <path fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.5794" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="m 21.839862,14.517191 c 6.543622,-2.443842 17.518669,6.349048 17.518669,6.349048 0,0 7.88428,-1.486434 11.87507,-1.528474 4.67538,-0.04925 11.404772,1.881199 11.404772,1.881199 0,0 4.768975,-6.719246 8.112672,-7.995098 7.503869,-2.863245 10.884649,0.342529 11.875072,1.8812 8.481775,13.176866 1.8812,27.159819 1.8812,27.159819 C 93.780821,65.991507 80.780864,77.73405 71.456496,84.709438 68.017059,87.12391 55.632924,92.733566 50.763301,92.822111 47.510105,92.881236 37.5689,90.338555 26.895584,83.063394 5.929735,68.77262 14.90294,45.43941 14.90294,45.43941 c 0,0 -6.0107737,-13.116858 -1.293325,-23.162272 1.586908,-3.379188 2.127713,-5.480838 8.230247,-7.759947 z"
       style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.23278654px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1">
         </path>
      </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
<!-- mask end -->
   
</div>
```

Comment: А как их ставить расскажите? я тут недавно(

Comment: @EugeneGellert Благодарю. Задавайте ещё вопросы по svg/ Интересная и переспективная тема